# Blur on headline

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, blur

**please check the screenshot how the blur background should work,**
**http://prntscr.com/7sfjwd**

I am using parallax theme in shopify,

http://bluerock-2.myshopify.com/pages/contact
store pw: thuich

I want to know how to apply this blur effect? I tried manipulating in -webkit-filter and opacity and its not giving a good result, others told me that I need a plug-in but I don't know how to apply it. thanks :D

Comment: Post some code to under stand the prob or create a problem space ins **jsfiddle**

Comment: Have you seen the screenshot? that's how should it look like :)

Comment: @JasperAbaricia have you seen how other people use this site? Have you seen this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ?

Comment: Screen shot is fine! But people here aren't supposed to help you with complete code! you need show what you've tried with code pasted! and your 2nd link asks for login!

Comment: Actually all this links should be useful! http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking Welcome to SO!

Comment: ohh sorry,.. i will prepare what code i had tried. one moment

Answer (score 1):

This should give you an idea:

```css
#container{
  font: 16px/1.1 sans-serif;
  overflow:auto;
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2oB8.jpg) fixed center;
  text-align:center;
}

h1{
  display:inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color:#fff;
  position:relative;
  z-index:20;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #fff;
  padding:10px 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:30px;
}

h1:after{
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;
  background: red url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2oB8.jpg) fixed center;
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  -moz-filter: blur(4px);
  -o-filter: blur(4px);
  -ms-filter: blur(4px);
  filter: blur(4px);
}
```

```html
  <div id="container">
      <h1>CONTACT</h1>
  </div>
```